# Do interfaces not care about the name of the method when using Lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, interface, lambda, delegates, expression

I guess I am a little confused by a couple of lines of code I have seen.

The first one:

```
      IEnumerable<SignalViewModel> SelectionQuery =
            from SignalViewModel svm in AvailableSignalsListView.SelectedItems
            orderby AvailableSignalsListView.Items.IndexOf(svm)
            select svm;

      _GraphViewerViewModel.SelectAvailableSignals(SelectionQuery);
```

makes sense to me because the orderby defined here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

takes a source and a key selector. I am guessing that the query portion
orderby `AvailableSignalsListView.Items.IndexOf(svm)` creates a lambda expression and calls

```
Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)
```

with the `IEnumerable<TSource>` being `AvailableSignalsListView.SelectedItems`
and the `Func<TSource, TKey>` being a lambda expression created from the query statement along the lines of

```
svm => AvailableSignalsListView.Items.IndexOf(svm);
```

This one makes sense to me though i'm uncertain if my understanding of the details is correct.

The second one,

```
List<SignalViewModel> mySelectedItems = new List<SignalViewModel>();

      //sort version
      foreach (SignalViewModel svm in AvailableSignalsListView.SelectedItems)
      {
        mySelectedItems.Add(svm);
      }
      mySelectedItems.Sort((x,y) => AvailableSignalsListView.Items.IndexOf(x).CompareTo(AvailableSignalsListView.Items.IndexOf(y)));
```

doesn't make sense because sort takes an icomparer. I can accept that an icomparer only needs a function as defined by its interface (that takes two items and returns an int). However, how does the computer know what function name to give the delegate behind the scenes? or do interfaces not actually care about the names of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several overloads to `List.Sort`.  [One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an `IComparer` interface, and [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a `Comparison` delegate.  This is using the latter.

If you had a method that only accepted an interface you couldn't pass in a delegate; that wouldn't work.

Comment: ah sorry somehow I missed that, somehow must have read comparer as icomparer. nice to know I'm not going crazy. Thanks for the response.